# Porqué se usa [0] Javascript

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Ejemplo aprenderaprogramar.com</title><meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
function ejemplo() {
var htmlADevolver = '';
var colorUsuario = prompt('Elija color red, yellow o blue');
if(colorUsuario != 'red' && colorUsuario != 'yellow' && colorUsuario != 'blue'){colorUsuario = false;}else{colorUsuario = colorUsuario;}
htmlADevolver += colorUsuario ? '<h1 style="background-color:'+colorUsuario+
';"> Usted eligió '+colorUsuario+'</h1>' : '<h1>No eligió color</h1>';
var nodoBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
nodoBody.innerHTML = nodoBody.innerHTML + htmlADevolver;
}
</script>
</head>
<body><div id="cabecera"><h2>Cursos aprenderaprogramar.com</h2><h3>Ejemplos JavaScript</h3></div>
<div style="color:blue;" id ="pulsador" onclick="ejemplo()"> Probar </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Porqué se usa***

```
var nodoBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
```

en `[0]` ?

Comment: _getElementsByTagName_ retorna un colección , se usa para acceder al primer elemento con el _tag_   _body_

Comment: pero el  tag body, siempre habrá uno o no?

Comment: devuelve solo <body> ? o también </body>

Comment: Si, pero ese comando no sabe cuantos 'x' te va a devolver, puede que x = body o sea div, por eso te devuelve un array.

Comment: y en caso de no escoger el indice , se escogen automaticamente todos o ninguno?

Comment: Técnicamente devuelve todo el contenido qué hay dentro del tag _body_ incluyendo el cierre de este, en el caso de no escoger índice devuelve la colección.

Comment: pero te los devuelve como Array así que tendrás que crear tu la iteracion para manejarlos

Comment: entonces si no especifico indice en el body, me devuelve el tag body y todos los tags que esten dentro de este?

Comment: te devuelve un array de todos los tags

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Así es , en todo caso debería comprobar cosas como por ejemplo hacer un simple `console.log` de `nobody` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entre los conceptos básicos de programación está el de colección.

En JavaScript, a partir de ECMAScript 6,

- Las colecciones pueden ser ordenadas mediantes claves/llaves (en inglés keys) o mediante índices.
- A una colección ordenada mediante índices se le conoce como matriz o arreglo (en inglés array).
- La numeración de índices comienza en 0.
- El colocar los corchetes inmediatamente después de un objeto y entre estos una clave o número sirve para llamar al miembro correspondiente de la colección.

El método `getElementsByTagName(tagname)` devuelve una colección, la cual puede ser una colección vacía, de uno o más miembros.

Considerando lo anterior,

`document.getElementsByTagName('body')` devuelve una colección formada por todos los elementos con la etiqueta `body`, si sólo hay uno, como es el caso del HTML incluído en la pregunta, la colección tendrá un sólo miembro, para llamar a ese miembro se usa el índice `0`, que corresponde al primer miembro de la colección, lo cual se realiza de la siguiente forma:

`document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]`

Si no quieres usar un método que devuelve una colección, usa `getElementById('id')`,pero para ello deberá agregar un el atributo id al elemento, que en este caso es `body`.

Comment: al colocar [0] en body ,me devuelve todo lo dentro de <body></body> ? o solo <body></body> en sí? y no su contenido ?

Comment: Esa ya es otra pregunta :)

Comment: gracias rubén !!

Comment: No hay de que Eduardo. Si no lo has hecho aún, es recomendable que leas [¿Cómo dar las gracias a los usuarios que responden a mis preguntas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1624/65)

Comment: Eduardo, colocar [0] devuelve un objeto DOM tipo, HTMLBodyElement que incluye todos el arbol interno de la pagina. No necesitas acceso al HTML en si, sino a lo que el navegador utiliza internamente que es ese objeto que mencione.  `<body>...</body>`  es solo una representacion de texto, internamente se usa el objeto.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName()` retorna una coleccion de elementos, sin importar de tag se trate.Si no hay elementos retorna una coleccion vacia. Si hay un solo elemento, este esta en la posicion 0 (cero), y asi sigue.

El `[0]` es para obtener el unico elemento body que hay en la pagina.

Comment: @Ruben me refiero a la pagina explicitamente, no al array. Por lo tanto es apropiado como esta.